# unable to generate APK file react-native Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'D:\native'

Tags: android, react-native, apk, signed-apk, bundle-release-js-and-assets

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTemL.png)

Hello world, I am newbie to react native and facing difficulty to generate apk file for my project.

getting a strange error when running command "gradlew bundleRelease" the process starts but after 2 minutes it generates a file in base directory named "native" and then throws error that "D:\native" already exists.

Comment: I am also getting the same error.. Did u get any solution so far?

Comment: Same here. Any solution?